# A board and stones

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need help with this question I encountered:

> I have a board the size of $10 \times 10$. I put six stones on the board randomly. I can't put two stones in the same square. If I had at least one row or column with more than one stone, I take all the stones off the board and start again. What is the probability that only in the ninth try there will be no rows and columns with more than one stone?

I am confused. Do I need the probability of two stones in the same square? And then multiply those probabilities till I get to $P(X = 9)$?

Comment: Presumably "randomly" means that you choose uniformly at random from all the empty squares.  If so, you exclude the possibility of getting two per square.  If you meant something different, you should indicate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the first stone everywhere. Then, in the second move, there are $9^2 = 81$ valid and $99 - 81 = 18$ invalid moves remaining (one is already taken by the stone). In the third, there are $8^2 = 64$ and $98 - 64 = 34$ valid and invalid moves, respectively. Continuing like this, we find that the probability $p$ of a valid setting (i.e., all six stones in different rows and columns), equals:

$$p = \frac{81}{99} \cdot \frac{64}{98} \cdot \frac{49}{97} \cdot \frac{36}{96} \cdot \frac{25}{95} \approx 0.02663$$

To have this working on the ninth try, the first eight attempts must fail, while the ninth must succeed. The probability of this happening, equals:

$$(1 - p)^8 \cdot p \approx 0.02146$$

Comment: That is the probability of placing _seven_ stones, not six.